# Jenkins GitHub plugin Scan Organization Triggers

Tags: jenkins, github

On the `Configuration` page of a Jenkins GitHub (v1.28.0) plugin organization, there is a section where you can set Jenkins to periodically scan the organization. I have turned this option off as I do not want Jenkins to build PRs or branches periodically.

[image: scan organization trigger]

However, this did not change the option on the repositories within the organization. In a repository, there is a `View Configuration` option, which still shows this.

[image: repository configuration]

I can uncheck the option here, but there is **no save button** and `View Configuration` certainly makes it sound like it is read-only. Even if I remove the repository from the Jenkins configuration and then re-add it, it still appears with the box checked.

How can I stop Jenkins from running builds on these repositories automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there's no way to do this in the UI, you can do this with a Groovy script.

```
// Update the PeriodicFolderTrigger of each job inside of a Cloudbees folder.
// Useful for updating individual repos as you cannot do this through the UI.
// Adapted from https://github.com/cloudbees/jenkins-scripts/blob/6eb3bfe58b2c87081966b77f91b0be06da7daad3/setOrgFolderIndex.groovy
import com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.PeriodicFolderTrigger
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import jenkins.branch.OrganizationFolder

println "Multibranch Items\n-------"
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject.class).each { it.triggers
       .findAll { k,v -> v instanceof com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.PeriodicFolderTrigger }
       .each { k,v -> setInterval(it) }                                                                                               
}

def setInterval(folder) {
  println "[INFO] : Updating ${folder.name}... " 
  folder.getTriggers().find {triggerEntry ->
    def key = triggerEntry.key
    if (key instanceof PeriodicFolderTrigger.DescriptorImpl){
      println "[INFO] : Current interval : " + triggerEntry.value.getInterval()
      // Valid intervals are here:
      // https://github.com/jenkinsci/cloudbees-folder-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cloudbees/hudson/plugins/folder/computed/PeriodicFolderTrigger.java#L261-L278
      def newInterval = new PeriodicFolderTrigger("28d")
      folder.addTrigger(newInterval)
      folder.save()
      println "[INFO] : New interval : " + newInterval.getInterval()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to keep the trigger for the organization itself and disable the "Child Scan Triggers". So you'll end up with something like this.

[image: Organization Scan enabled]

However, your Child Trigger (the repository themselves) will be disabled if you uncheck "Periodically if not otherwise run".

[image: Child Trigger Disabled]

This should prevent the automatic triggering for the Org repos. This solution is not bullet-proof though. If your Jenkins restarts the repository triggers will execute and perform a branch indexing, which in turn will trigger builds.